# installation wxPython on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: python, ubuntu, installation, wxpython

hope somebody helps me to install wxPython.
I have ubuntu 11.10 and there is no build package for it.
I used this page ( http://wxpython.org/BUILD.html ) as guidance to install
after installing, I run

```
>python

>>>import wx

 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "wx/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from wx._core import *
  File "wx/_core.py", line 4, in <module>
    import _core_
ImportError: libwx_gtk2u_adv-2.9.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What should do to fix it?
thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow [the instructions for installing on Ubuntu or Debian](http://wiki.wxpython.org/InstallingOnUbuntuOrDebian).

EDIT: Actually, you don't even need to do that, since it's [in the main repos](http://packages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search_packages.pl?keywords=wxPython&searchon=all&subword=1&version=dapper&release=all):

```
sudo aptitude install python-wxgtk2.8
```

Comment: Thank you dude! It is in repository. In the wxpython.org they wrote that there is not version in repository for ubuntu 11.10. Thanks again )